# ORDER BY discrepancies with/without ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am usign: **PostgreSQL 9.6.3**

Today I've faced a very strange discrepancies in selection result depending on whether `ROW_NUMBER()` function call present or not present in my query

---

The first query with output looks like:

```
SELECT "users"."id", "users"."ranking" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."mentor" = 't'  ORDER BY "users"."ranking" DESC LIMIT 10;
```

And it's result:

```
   id   |     ranking
--------+-----------------
     33 | 4.36852371411504
 320145 | 4.08071526845868
 301573 | 3.98071042776232
  25649 | 3.92019074023998
 159117 | 3.92019074023998
   3218 | 3.86067914389982
 635532 | 3.79788768116942
    559 | 3.73163558856403
 359211 | 3.73163558856403
 635548 | 3.66173214016947
```

---

The second query is very similar to the first, but I've added `ROW_NUMBER()` selection:

```
SELECT "users"."id", "users"."ranking", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "users"."ranking" DESC) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."mentor" = 't' ORDER BY "users"."ranking" DESC LIMIT 10;
```

And it's result:

```
   id   |     ranking      | row_number 
--------+------------------+------------
     33 | 4.36852371411504 |          1
 320145 | 4.08071526845868 |          2
 301573 | 3.98071042776232 |          3
 159117 | 3.92019074023998 |          4
  25649 | 3.92019074023998 |          5
   3218 | 3.86067914389982 |          6
 635532 | 3.79788768116942 |          7
    559 | 3.73163558856403 |          8
 359211 | 3.73163558856403 |          9
 419302 | 3.66173214016947 |         10
```

---

As you see, it looks like in first case result is sorted by `id` in `ASC` order, while in second query it's get sorted by `id` in `DESC` order, but my queries are the same. I know **HOW** to solve this issue, but I want to understand **WHY** is it happen?

Comment: "it looks like in first case result is sorted by id in ASC order, while in second query it's get sorted by id in DESC order": No, in both cases the results are ordered by `ranking`, as defined by both queries. The difference is when `ranking` values between two records are identical; in that case it is unpredictable which of those records comes first.

Comment: I can't see any "ordering" in the values for `ID` in those two results. Neither ascending nor descending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple rows with the same value in the `order by`.

In relational databases, sorting is *unstable*.  When there are ties in the key values, the rows are in an indeterminate order.  This is what you are seeing.

The instability of SQL sorts is a direct result of the fact that relational tables (and result sets) represent *unordered* sets.  There is no additional ordering.  The solution is simple.  For a stable sort, just add an additional unique key to the `order by`:

```
order by ranking desc, id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know, that `id` ordering solve my issue and I think you are right about unstable ordering, but I always get `ASC` order without `ROW_NUMBER()` and always `DESC` order with `ROW_NUMBER()`. I will wait for some additional answers. If there won't be anything better, I will mark your question as a solution.

Comment: @AntonTkachov . . . You cannot depend on the ordering of rows with the same key values.

Comment: @AntonTkachov What you see is a result of unspecified implementation details and can change from version to version and even from query plan to query plan. You simply **cannot** depend on orderings you do not request.

Comment: @AntonTkachov The order is *arbitrary*, but it is not *random*. If you repeat the exact same query on the exact same data, without any changes to the server, the computer will calculate the same operations, and give the same result. But change the query, the data, even the memory configuration of the server, and it might process the data slightly differently, the rows will be in a different order in memory, and will show up in that order in your results. You can't predict the order from the query, nor with any certainty know what factors will affect that order.

Comment: @IMSoP . . . What you say is not even necessarily true.  On a machine with multiple processors, even keeping everything the same can result in a different ordering in some database (although Postgres might have some logic underneath that does result in the same ordering each time).

Comment: @GordonLinoff True. What I was trying to get across is that it should not be surprising if the result is stable by coincidence, because nothing is actively trying to randomise it. Most query plans are deterministic if you go down to a low enough level of implementation, so the order is theoretically predictable if you knew every factor that might have an effect. Knowing all those factors is unfeasible because there are so many of them, but *often* re-running the same query won't change any of them, so you get the *illusion* of a stable order.

Comment: @IMSoP and Gordon. Thanks a lot for your clarifications